Unable to delete prometheus data in specific time range
I am trying to remove some data in a specified time range
grafana data
prometheus label
curl -u promadmin -X POST 'http://127.0.0.1:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series?match[]=flavibot_guild_removed&start=2024-08-13T11:00:00.000Z&end=2024-08-13T12:00:00.000Z'

the command is executed, and there are no errors and my data is still there.
I also tried to remove start and end, and it doesn't change anything
I executed this request on the wrong server

Do you get 204 from the method call? What is your mechanism for demonstrating the data is not deleted? The API documents two caveats with the method

First I executed my first request on the wrong server so that why it doesn't have effect when I was looking.
I executed this request on the "right" server It deleted all my datas lol with a code 000 and now if a use it again I have a code 204 so maybe next time it will works thanks
curl \
--silent \
--request POST \
--data-urlencode "match[]=guild_added" \
--data-urlencode "start=2024-08-19T11:23:21.000Z" \
--data-urlencode "end=2024-08-19T11:23:24.000Z" \
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series \
--write-out 'Response Code: %{response_code}\n'


Here's an example using a generic Prometheus instance:
Prometheus w/ Admin API
VERS="v2.54.0"

# Enables Admin API
podman run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--publish=9090:9090/tcp \
docker.io/prom/prometheus:${VERS} \
--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
--web.enable-admin-api \
--web.enable-lifecycle

delete_series
Give it time to scrape metrics multiple times
METRIC="up"

printf "Current timestamps\n"

START=$(date +%s -d "2 minutes ago")
curl \
--silent \
--get \
--data-urlencode "query=${METRIC}" \
--data-urlencode "start=${START}" \
--data-urlencode "end=$(date +%s)" \
--data-urlencode "step=10" \
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query_range \
| jq -r '.data.result[].values[][0]'

END=$(date +%s) # Now as UNIX Epoch
printf "Deleting before %s\n" ${END}

curl \
--silent \
--request POST \
--data-urlencode "match[]=${METRIC}" \
--data-urlencode "end=${END}" \
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series \
--write-out 'Response Code: %{response_code}\n'

Expect 204
Yields e.g.:
1723650326
1723650336
1723650346
1723650356
1723650366
1723650376
1723650386
1723650396
1723650406
1723650416
1723650426
1723650436
1723650446
Deleting before 1723650447
Response Code: 204


NOTE Timestamps are all before 1723650447

Test
Wait again for more scrapes to be made then repeat the query_range with current times:
METRIC="up"
START=$(date +%s -d "2 minutes ago")
curl \
--silent \
--get \
--data-urlencode "query=${METRIC}" \
--data-urlencode "start=${START}" \
--data-urlencode "end=$(date +%s)" \
--data-urlencode "step=10" \
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query_range \
| jq -r '.data.result[].values[][0]'

Yields:
1723650456
1723650466
1723650476
1723650486
1723650496
1723650506


NOTE No timestamps are before 1723650447

